# Trying to connect D3 Nodes from "flat" JSON to make company heirarchy graph

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, graph, hierarchy

I am trying to create a company hierarchy graph using D3..using the code from this example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2949981

Is there a way to create that graph from this json:

```
      links = [
        {
            "Source": "1",
            "Target": "2",
        },
        {
            "Source": "1",
            "Target" : "3"
        },
        {
            "Source": "2",
            "Target": "4",
        },
        {
            "Source": "2",
            "Target": "5",
        },
        {
           "Source" : "3",
           "Target" " "6"
        }
    ]

      nodes = [
        {
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "TEST NODE ONE",
            "Url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "TEST NODE TWO",
            "Url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3",
            "Name": "TEST NODE THREE",
            "Url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            "Id": "4",
            "Name": "TEST NODE FOUR",
            "Url": "http://www.reddit.com"
        }
         {
            "Id": "5",
            "Name": "TEST NODE FIVE",
            "Url": "http://www.stack.com"
        }
        {
            "Id": "6",
            "Name": "TEST NODE SIX",
            "Url": "http://www.six.com"
        }

    ]
```

I want to make each node a rectangle where I can put the employee name, which comes from the "nodes" json. But connect each node with the data in the "link" json. Feel free to alter the link json to have it make more sense to you.

I would also like to make the lines connecting the nodes straight and make it vertical as well but my main concern is displaying the graph on the page via the json above.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `links`, which associates between ids of nodes, to an array that associates — via reference — between the actual objects in `nodes`. A simple loop does this:

```
var links = [ { "Source": "1", "Target": "2" }, ... ]
var nodes = [ { "Id": "1", "Name": "TEST NODE ONE", "Url": "http://www.google.com" }, ... ]

var cachedNodesById = {};
var linksBetweenNodeObjs = links.map(funciont(link) {
  return {
    source: nodeById(link.Source),
    target: nodeById(link.Target)
  };
});

function nodeById(id) {
  // return the node if it's been found before, otherwise loop over the
  // array to find it
  if(cachedNodesById[id] != null) { return cachedNodesById[id]; }
  else {
    for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      if(nodes[i].Id == id) { return cachedNodesById[id] = nodes[i]; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, when I run that I get the following console error:  "Can not read property 1 of undefined" at                                         "if(cachedNodesById[id] != null) { return cachedNodesById[id]; }"

Comment: @bschmitty You error did not show up in the comment, but anyway, I found a mistake and updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that works for building the data but what exactly should i be passing into this line then from the link I posted:  var nodes = tree.nodes(links[0].Source). I can't get that to build the tree when I console.log "nodes" I am only getting ["1"]. But when I did it the way it shows in the link with "forEach" I don't get any x and y coordinates because the links json is an array and not an object. Thanks again

Comment: @bschmitty oh, I missed the fact that this is a tree layout, not a force layout or network diagram. The data needs to be further transformed into a hierarchical one (with `children` array for each non-leaf node). I'm not able to look into this right now. You should be able to figure it out, especially since the example you're using provides lots of guidance. Also note that `links[0].Source` is incorrect in that `source` should be lowercased (unless you up-case it in the code I gave you).

Comment: thanks for the help yesterday. I am working with a force layout now, it makes more sense I think. I posted this question, I was curious if you could help me here at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35900276/controlling-the-display-of-graphs-with-force-layout-without-specifying-x-y-coord