# Controlling the display of graphs with force layout without specifying x/y coordinates in nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, hierarchy, force-layout

Take this example:

```
  var graph = {
        "nodes": [
            { "name": "Myriel", "group": 1 }, //0
            { "name": "Napoleon", "group": 1 }, //1
            { "name": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1 }, //2
            { "name": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1 }, //3
            { "name": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1 },//4
            { "name": "Geborand", "group": 1 }
            // { "name": "Champtercier", "group": 1 }
        ],
        "links": [
            { "source": 0, "target": 1, "value": 50},
            { "source": 1, "target": 2, "value": 50},
            { "source": 2, "target": 0, "value": 50},
            { "source": 3, "target": 4, "value": 50},
            { "source": 4, "target": 5, "value": 50},
            { "source": 5, "target": 3, "value": 50}
        ]
    } 

   var force = d3.layout.force()
        .linkDistance(function (d){
            return d.value;
        })
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .links(graph.links)
        .friction(0)
        .chargeDistance(200)

   var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
            return Math.sqrt(d.value);
            });

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")

    force.on('tick', function () {
        node.attr('r', 15)
            .attr('cx', function (d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function (d) { return d.y; });

        link.attr('x1', function (d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr('y1', function (d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr('x2', function (d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr('y2', function (d) { return d.target.y; });
    });

     force.start();
```

When I am passing in nodes with no specified x and y coordinates is there a way to control the layout of the the graphs. For example, my links above are creating two separate triangle graphs, but sometime they appear on top of each other. I'm wondering if there is a property that I can use (friction, chargeDistance, charge, etc). that would allow me to set the two triangle graphs next to each other on the same line? Or do I need to specify x and y coord to get that look? It looks like friction helps move them apart but its hard to tell.

I was also hoping to get clarifcation - does the first object in my nodes array correspond to the first object in my links array? Are they associated because they both have an index of 0 or how does that work? I'm having a hard time tracking it. Does the first nodes object have a source of 0 then and its target is the second object in the nodes array (which would have a source of 1, target 1)?

My last question is there a way to display the nodes without using "end" or "tick". I'd like for the graphs to just appear on the page when it loads but with "end" it takes too long to show and with "tick" they slide onto the page which I don't want. When I tried to add the link attr like I have in the "tick" function I get an undefined error because it can't find x and y coords.

Thanks

Comment: You can play around with the parameters, but in general that won't allow you to achieve any exact shapes. For this, you need to constrain the nodes' positions manually as in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1129492).

Comment: Thanks Lars, yeah I didn't really think so but wanted to confirm. I need something like two triangles upright sitting next to each other, etc. I'm trying to add rectangles with text inside onto each node rather then the circle, shouldn't I just be able to change "circle" to "rect" and add height and width attributes? I'm not able to translate some of the other examples I've seen. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you don't need the force layout for this at all, you could specify the positions statically.

Comment: This is a custom angular component, so the user of the directive is creating the graph based on the nodes, edges, etc that are passed into the directive. Playing around with different libraries. Is it possible to add a rectangle with text inside based on my example code above? Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible, but if you're not using the force layout the code for that will not resemble your code above at all.

Comment: the code above will be inside the component, they'll just be passing in the graph object I have, along with any other attributes like linkDistance, friction, etc. But it will always be a force layout unless they specify they want a tree then the tree layout will be used. Can't seem to find any examples of how to add a rectangle with text inside it.... I have text inside a circle but apparently rect doesn't work the same.

Comment: It should work the same way.